How to avoid form reload in parent component using Inertia?
I have two components. One is parent that has simple form with description and titke, etc. Another one is a modal that updates a picture. Now everytime I update a picture, the unsaved data from form(parent component) disappears. It seems the page reloads. How can I avoid that?
CourseInformation.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Alert,
  Button,
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
  TextField,
  Card,
  CardContent, CardMedia, MenuItem, Snackbar,
} from '@mui/material';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import EditIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Edit';
import Headline from '@/Components/Ui/Headline';
import { Course, User } from '@/types';
import { __ } from 'matice';
import CourseDetailsHeader from '@/Pages/Courses/Partials/CourseDetailsHeader';
import CourseDetailsAside from '@/Pages/Courses/Partials/CourseDetailsAside';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import { useInertiaForm } from 'use-inertia-form';
import route from '../../../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import avatarPlaceholder from '../../../images/auth-bg.jpg';
import CourseInformationImageModal from '@/Pages/Courses/CourseInformationImageModal';
import RichTextEditor from '@/Components/Ui/RichTextEditor';

interface CourseInformationProps {
  course: Course;
  clientId: number;
  authors: User[];
}

export default function CourseInformation({ course, clientId, authors }: CourseInformationProps) {
  const [courseFormModalOpen, setCourseFormModalOpen] = useState(false);


  const form = useInertiaForm({
    course: {
      title: '',
      short_description: '',
      description: '',
      course_goal: '',
      client_id: clientId,
      author_id: '',
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (course) {
      form.setData('course.title', course.title);
      form.setData('course.short_description', course.short_description);
      form.setData('course.description', course.description);
      form.setData('course.course_goal', course.course_goal);
      form.setData('course.author_id', course.author_id);
    }
  }, [course]);

  const updateCourseInfo = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
      form.patch(route('courses.update', course.id), {
        onSuccess: () => {
        },
        onError: (errors) => {
          console.log(errors);
        },
      });
  };

  function openImageForm(course: Course | null = null) {
    setCourseFormModalOpen(true);
  }

  function closeImageForm() {
    setCourseFormModalOpen(false);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Snackbar
        open={form.recentlySuccessful}
        anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'right' }}
      >
        <Alert
          severity="success"
          variant="filled"
          sx={{ width: '100%' }}
          icon={<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas', 'check']} fontSize={'inherit'} />}
        >
          Course information successfully updated
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
      <Box>
        {courseFormModalOpen && (<CourseInformationImageModal course={{...course}} open={openImageForm} closeModal={closeImageForm} />
        )}
        <CourseDetailsHeader course={course} />

        <Grid container spacing={4} sx={{ mt: 2.5 }}>
          <Grid xs={12} xl={8}>
            <Headline
              variant="h2"
              title={__('courses.information')}
              sx={{ mb: 2.5 }}
            />

            <form onSubmit={updateCourseInfo}>
              <Card>
                <CardContent>
                  <DialogContent>
                    <Grid container >
                      <Grid container>
                        <Grid xs={12} md={12}>
                          <Box>
                            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                              <Grid
                                xs={12}
                                sm={3}
                                sx={{
                                  display: 'flex',
                                  flexDirection: 'column',
                                  alignItems: 'flex-end',
                                  position: 'relative',
                                }}
                              >
                                <CardMedia
                                  component="img"
                                  image={course.thumbnail_url ?? avatarPlaceholder}
                                  sx={{
                                    width: '100%',
                                    height: '100%',
                                    borderRadius: '5px',
                                  }}
                                />
                                <Button
                                  onClick={(event) => {
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    openImageForm(course);
                                  }}
                                  component="label"
                                  role={undefined}
                                  variant="contained"
                                  tabIndex={-1}
                                  size="xs"
                                  sx={{
                                    position: 'absolute',
                                    top: '12px',
                                    right: '12px',
                                    backgroundColor: 'black',
                                    borderRadius: '4px',
                                  }}
                                >
                                  <EditIcon sx={{ fontSize: 16 }} />
                                </Button>
                              </Grid>
                              <Grid xs={12} sm={9} sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', mt: '20px' }}>
                                <TextField
                                  fullWidth
                                  id='courseTitle'
                                  size="small"
                                  sx={{ mb: 2 }}
                                  type="text"
                                  label={__('courses.title')}
                                  value={form.data.course.title}
                                  onChange={e => form.setData('course.title', e.currentTarget.value)}
                                  error={!!form.getError('course.title')}
                                  helperText={form.getError('course.title')}
                                />
                                <TextField
                                  fullWidth
                                  size="small"
                                  sx={{ mb: 2 }}
                                  type="text"
                                  label={__('courses.short_description')}
                                  value={form.data.course.short_description}
                                  onChange={e => form.setData('course.short_description', e.currentTarget.value)}
                                  error={!!form.getError('course.short_description')}
                                  helperText={form.getError('course.short_description')}
                                  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: !!form.data.course.short_description }}
                                />
                              </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                          </Box>
                        </Grid>
                      </Grid>

                    </Grid>

                  </DialogContent>
                </CardContent>
              </Card>
              <Card sx={{ mt: 2.5 }}>
                <CardContent>
                  <Box>
                    <Typography
                      fontWeight={700}
                      fontFamily={'Assistant'}
                      fontSize={'20px'}
                      sx={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}
                    >
                      {__('courses.author')} / {__('courses.course_instructor')}
                    </Typography>

                    <FormControl fullWidth sx={{ mt: '20px' }}>
                      <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">{__('courses.select_member')}</InputLabel>
                      <TextField
                        select
                        id="demo-simple-select"
                        label={__('courses.select_member')}
                        onChange={e => form.setData('course.author_id', e.target.value)}
                        value={form.data.course.author_id}
                        error={!!form.getError('course.author_id')}
                        helperText={form.getError('course.author_id')}
                        fullWidth
                      >
                        {authors.map(author => (

                          <MenuItem key={author.id} value={author.id}>{author.first_name}</MenuItem>
                        ))
                        }
                      </TextField>
                    </FormControl>

                  </Box>
                </CardContent>
              </Card>


              <Card sx={{ mt: 2.5 }}>
                <CardContent>
                  <Box>
                    <Typography
                      fontWeight={700}
                      fontFamily={'Assistant'}
                      fontSize={'20px'}
                      sx={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}
                    >
                      {__('courses.description')}
                    </Typography>
                    <RichTextEditor
                      value={form.data.course.description}
                      onChange={(value: any) => form.setData('course.description', value)}
                      error={!!form.getError('course.description')}
                      helperText={form.getError('course.description')}
                    />
                  </Box>
                </CardContent>
              </Card>

              <Card sx={{ mt: 2.5}}>
                <CardContent>
                  <Box>
                    <Typography
                      fontWeight={700}
                      fontFamily={'Assistant'}
                      fontSize={'20px'}
                      sx={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}
                    >
                      {__('courses.course_goal')}
                    </Typography>
                    <RichTextEditor
                      value={form.data.course.course_goal}
                      onChange={(value: any) => form.setData('course.course_goal', value)}
                      error={!!form.getError('course.course_goal')}
                      helperText={form.getError('course.course_goal')}
                    />

                  </Box>
                </CardContent>


                <DialogActions>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="secondary"
                    disabled={form.processing}
                    type="submit"
                  >
                    {__('default.save')}
                  </Button>
                </DialogActions>
              </Card>
            </form>
          </Grid>
          <CourseDetailsAside course={course} />
        </Grid>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};


CourseInformationImageModal.tsx
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import { Alert, Button, CardMedia, DialogActions, DialogContent, DialogTitle, Snackbar, Stack } from '@mui/material';
import { __ } from 'matice';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import UploadFileIcon from '@mui/icons-material/UploadFile';
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';
import { useInertiaForm } from 'use-inertia-form';
import { Course } from '@/types';
import route from '../../../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';


type ImageFormProps = {
  course: Course
  open: any;
  closeModal: () => void;
}
export default function CourseInformationImageModal({ course, open, closeModal}: ImageFormProps){

  const [previewUrl, setPreviewUrl] = React.useState<string | null>(course?.thumbnail_url || null);
  const [showSuccessSnackbar, setShowSuccessSnackbar] = React.useState(false);

  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({
    accept: { 'image/*': [] },
    onDrop: (acceptedFiles) => {
      form_thumbnail.setData('course.thumbnail', acceptedFiles[0]);
      setPreviewUrl(URL.createObjectURL(acceptedFiles[0]));

    },
  });

  const form_thumbnail = useInertiaForm({
    _method:'PUT',
    course: {
      thumbnail: null as File | null,
    },
  });
  function onSubmit(e: React.FormEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
    form_thumbnail.post(route('courses.updateImage', { course: course.id }), {
      onSuccess: () => {
        setShowSuccessSnackbar(true);
        closeModal();
      },
      onError: (errors) => {
        form_thumbnail.setError(errors);
      },
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Snackbar
        open={showSuccessSnackbar}
        autoHideDuration={6000}
        onClose={() => setShowSuccessSnackbar(false)}
        anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'right' }}
      >
        <Alert
          severity="success"
          variant="filled"
          sx={{ width: '100%' }}
          icon={<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas', 'check']} fontSize={'inherit'} />}
        >
          Course image updated successfully!
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>

      <Dialog open={open} onClose={closeModal} fullWidth={true} maxWidth={'xs'}>
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <DialogTitle>
            <Typography
              fontWeight={700}
              fontFamily={'Assistant'}
              fontSize={'20px'}
            >
              {__('courses.edit_course_image')}
            </Typography>
          </DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <Box {...getRootProps()}
                 sx={{
                   mt: 3,
                   height: 200,
                   border: '1px dashed var(--divider, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12))',
                   borderRadius: '4px',
                   display: 'flex',
                   justifyContent: 'center',
                   alignItems: 'center',
                 }}
            >
              <input {...getInputProps()} />
              {
                isDragActive ?
                  <Typography>{__('courses.drop_here')}</Typography> :
                  <>
                    <Box
                      sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                      <Stack sx={{ mb: 2 }}>
                        {
                          previewUrl ? (
                            <CardMedia
                              component='img'
                              image={previewUrl}
                              alt="Preview"
                              sx={{
                                maxWidth: '100%',
                                maxHeight: '70px',
                              }}
                            />
                          ) : (
                            <UploadFileIcon style={{ color: 'rgba(33, 150, 243, 1)', width: '30px', height: '34px' }} />
                          )
                        }
                      </Stack>
                      <Typography
                        sx={{
                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                          fontSize: '16px',
                          fontWeight: 400,
                          lineHeight: '28px',
                          letterSpacing: '0.15000000596046448px',
                          textAlign: 'left',
                        }}
                      >
                        {__('courses.upload_drag')}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography
                        sx={{
                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                          fontSize: '14px',
                          fontWeight: 400,
                          lineHeight: '20.02px',
                          letterSpacing: '0.17000000178813934px',
                          textAlign: 'center',
                          marginBottom: '5px',
                        }}
                      >
                        {__('courses.type_size')}
                      </Typography>
                    </Box>
                  </>
              }
            </Box>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button
              onClick={closeModal}
              sx={{ color: 'black' }}
            >
              {__('courses.back')}
            </Button>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="secondary"
              disabled={form_thumbnail.processing}
              type="submit"
            >
              {__('courses.save')}
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </form>
      </Dialog>
    </>
)
}


I tried different techniques such as using copy of the original object. I tried using onClick instead of onSubmit.
